# How do I use Hairnet properly?

Tags: modeling, particles

I have Just got the Hairnet extension but everytime I try to add the hair it says somethings missing, have I done something wrong? Could someone tell me how Hairnet?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, I honestly know nothing about this addon, but here https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Objects/HairNet#Sheets the wiki says "A rectangular mesh used to make a hair system must have one boundary edge **marked as a seam**. If an example mesh 4 faces wide and 3 faces tall is to be used, the bottom row of edges could be marked with a seam", so, did if this applies to your case, you set that seam?

Comment: I did add a seam but it didn't seem to work

Answer (score 1):

I tried the addon, here it seems to work.

If you set a seam on the "plane hair guide", like this
(note:I highlighted in red the "plane hair guide", in blue the "emitter")

[image]

then, in object mode, be sure to apply all transformations to the objects (location, rotation, scaling)

then you select those two in that order, and press this button

[image]

you should get something like this

[image]

which renders like this in blender render

[image]

I noticed though, that if you select the "emitter" (eg the head) first and after the "plane hair guide" (eg a custom shape) you get an error like "no seams were defined in plane", because it needs to be selected in the opposite way: first the "plane hair guide" (eg a custom shape), and then the  "emitter" (eg the head).

Otherwise, please describe how you set it up, or share the file on http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/, then paste the provided link editing your question: I'll take a look.

Comment: That seemed to work, sort of, except the hair is in the wrong spot, its in the middle of the circle, not on the edge.

Comment: Yes, that happened to me, but I forgot, as suggested, to apply all transformations (location, rotation, scale). After doing that, it was OK: try and report the result. I added this in the answer, too.

Comment: OH YEAH, I forgot about that bit, thanks heaps.

Comment: How do you do it when the mesh guides have different lengths?

Comment: I never tried, I just installed this to help you :) But this is also a different issue, and it needs to be explained in a different question, as this site requires a single question for each post... Open a new question, and there if you can share your file (see the end of my answer) I could take a look, and hopefully find a solution... meanwhile, if my answer helped, consider upvoting it, and if it solved you issue, you could accept it, so to show others, in the future, if it was helpful content.